# Using Taylor's inequality to approximate $4\cos(5^{\circ})$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am supposed to approximate $4\cos(5^{\circ})$ using Maclaurin Series and Taylor inequality to 4 decimal point accuracy.

Using,
$$|R_n(x)| \le {M\over{(n + 1)!}}|x - a|^{n + 1} \text{ for }|x - a| \le d$$
So, I have set up:
\begin{align*}
\left|R_2\left(\frac{\pi}{36}\right)\right| &\le {4\over{(2 + 1)!}}\left|\frac{\pi}{36} - 0\,\right|^{\,2 + 1} \approx  0.0004430\\
\left|R_3\left(\frac{\pi}{36}\right)\right| &\le {4\over{(3 + 1)!}}\left|\frac{\pi}{36} - 0\,\right|^{\,3 + 1} \approx  0.0000096658
\end{align*}

I am getting mixed up in using Taylor's inequality with an alternating series and the number of terms to use.  So, $|R_3|$ meets 4 decimal place accuracy but that means I would use only two terms. And $R_2(x)$ didn't meet the accuracy.

$$4\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{36}\right)=4-\frac{\frac{\pi}{36}^2}{2}+...$$

And when testing an alternating series with Taylor's Inequality, are you supposed to use $R_1(x)$ and $R_3(x)$ or $R_2(x)$ and $R_4(x)$ or sequential $R_2(x)$ and $R_3(x)$?

Comment: I think Cos should be added to n=4 not n=2.  Have I got that right?

Comment: In the expansion of $\cos(x)$ there are only even powers. So, if $n=2$ is not sufficient, use $n=4$ (just as you tell in the above comment)

Comment: Thank-you.  I found some information here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884490/correct-to-four-decimal-places.  So, when using Taylor's Inequality to find an error to four decimal place accuracy means using .00005 not 0.0001.

Comment: More precisely, you want (since it is a alternating series) that the remainder be smaller than $0.0001$